# Finding multiple regular expression matches in one line

Tags: php, regex

As for practice and later development, i'm working on a PHP router. For this router, my mapped routes could have parameters in them, a route looks like this:

> /home/{i:pageNum}/{s:userName}

There are now 2 variables in this route:

- The pageNum variable, which is an int type
- The userName variable, which is an string type

For capturing this data, i wrote this regular expression:

```
{((?<type>\D):)?(?<name>[a-zA-Z_-ÿ][a-zA-Z0-9_-ÿ]+)}
```

This works great, but the only problem with it is that it only captures the first variable only.

It does only capture more of these matches when I put a new route on a new line.

I tried capturing the whole regular expression by surrounding it by `(`'s and `)`'s. This did not work.

How can I make this regular expression so that it captures more matches on one line of text?

For calling this regular expression, I use the following PHP function:

```
preg_match("/{((?<type>\D):)?(?<name>[a-zA-Z_-ÿ][a-zA-Z0-9_-ÿ]+)}/", "/home/{i:pageNum}/{s:userName}", $matches);
```

Comment: What php function are you using to match?

Comment: can you show the php code where you use this regex? I assume the issue is that you are using [preg_match()](https://php.net/preg_match) instead of [preg_match_all()](https://php.net/preg_match_all). PHP has two separate functions for matching once vs global while some other languages just use a `//g` for global matching.

Comment: I updated my question, I'm using the preg_match() indeed.

Comment: Aside from that, your pattern looks fine:  https://regex101.com/r/bD1bM5/1 (notice I added the `g` modifier) with one exception that `{` is a special character in regex and should be escaped.

Comment: What about using preg_match_all?

Comment: Showing the difference with preg_match vs preg_match_all: https://3v4l.org/AOfXi

Comment: @JonathanKuhn What do you mean by the `g` modifier?

Comment: Whenever i use the `preg_match_all` function, my data get's all out of order, which i can't use it anymore then.

Comment: This `_-ÿ` is a range between underscore and `ÿ`, is that intended? This `a-zA-Z0-9_` can just be `\w`.

Comment: You can use the default `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` or `PREG_SET_ORDER`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: `g` modifier is irrelevant in php. Other languages use a `g` modifier to signify to match one or all. php just has two different functions. If you look at that regex101 link above, the box right of the regex says "g"

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `preg_match_all()` and `PREG_SET_ORDER`:

```
preg_match_all("/{((?<type>\D):)?(?<name>[a-zA-Z_-ÿ][a-zA-Z0-9_-ÿ]+)}/",
               "/home/{i:pageNum}/{s:userName}",
               $matches,
               PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Then:

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo $match['name'] . ' = ' . $match['type'];
}
```

Using the default `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` you could do:

```
$matches = array_combine($matches['name'], $matches['type']);

foreach($matches as $name => $type) {
    echo "$name = $type";
}
```

Comment: I completly forgot that I posted this question, and was not active on StackOverflow. Here by thanks for the answer, it is indeed the thing I need. My only question is, what does `PREG_SET_ORDER` and `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER ` do?

Comment: They just determine how the matches are returned in the array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php